# How do I make a loop run for X amount of times from user input?

Tags: java

I need to build a program that asks the user for a number and how many multiples of the number they want to see. The program will then display the entered number and the first x of its multiples. How do I make a loop run for X amount of times from user input? I need to make the multiples of the user inputted number list multiples for the number of multiples the user wants. It should execute like this:

---Multiples---

Enter a number: 8
Enter the number of multiples you would like to see for the number 8 :5

The first 5 multiples of 8 are: 8, 16, 24, 32, 40

**Here is My code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("---Multiples---\n");
    
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    int num = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the number of multiples you would like to see for the number "+num+" :");
    int multiples = keyboard.nextInt();
    
    System.out.print("\nThe first "+multiples+" multiples of "+num+" are: ");
    
    for(int x=1;x==multiples;x++)
    num = num*x;
    System.out.print(+num+ ", ");
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to start with debugger first

Comment: @DevilsHnd Seriously? A code-only answer in a comment? Please take the [tour] and read [answer] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment You seem to have missed or forgotten all the concepts described there.

Comment: `for(int x = 1; x <= multiples; x++) { System.out.print(num + "x" + x + " = " +  (num * x) + (x < multiples ? ", " : "")); }`. @Yunnosch, Indeed.

Comment: You make me seem clairvoyant. Cool. @DevilsHnd

Answer (score 1):

You have to fix your loop condition and put curly braces around your for loop to execute more than one statement. Try this:

```
for(int x = 1; x <= multiples; x++) {
    num = num * x;
    System.out.print(num + ", ");
}
```